# Changing Java code that writes double to CSV to write double[] to CSV (use case = WEKA library)

Tags: java, weka

I have written a Java program using the WEKA library that

1. trains a classification algorithm
2. runs predictions on an unlabeled data set using the trained algorithm
3. writes out the results to a .csv file

The problem is that it currently writes out the discrete classification results (i.e. which category the algorithm guesses that a row falls into). What I want is to write out the probability of a given class (e.g. if I am classifying rows as "spam" or "not spam" then I want the probability of spam to be the result).

My understanding is that to do this I need to use `distributionForInstance` instead of `classifyInstance` in my code. From [WEKA](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code):

> If you're interested in the distribution over all the classes, use the
>   method distributionForInstance(Instance). This method returns a double
>   array with the probability for each class.

**The problem I am running into is that with `classifyInstance` I was dealing with the `double` data type and with  `distributionForInstance` I am dealing with the `double[]` data type and apparently not adjusting my code correctly.**

Here is the working code that writes out the discreet predictions:

```
public class runPredictions {
public static void runPredictions(ArrayList al2) throws IOException, Exception{
    // Retrieve objects
    Instances newTest = (Instances) al2.get(0);
    Classifier clf = (Classifier) al2.get(1);

    // Print status
    System.out.println("Generating predictions...");

    // create copy
    Instances labeled = new Instances(newTest);

    // label instances
    for (int i = 0; i < newTest.numInstances(); i++) {
      double clsLabel = clf.classifyInstance(newTest.instance(i));
      labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);

    }
    System.out.println("Predictions complete! Writing output file to csv...");
    BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/hackr/Desktop/silverbullet_output.csv"));

    for (int i = 0; i < labeled.size(); i++)
    {
        outFile.write(labeled.get(i).toString());
        outFile.write("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("Output file written.");
    System.out.println("Completed successfully!");
    outFile.close();    
}    
}
```

Right now the code I'm working on has the following:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < labeled.size(); i++)

{
    double[] clsLabel = clf.distributionForInstance(newTest.instance(i));
    //outFile.write(labeled.get(i).toString());
    outFile.write(Double.toString(clsLabel[i]));
    outFile.write("\n");
}
```

and throws an

> Index out of bounds

error.

I also moved the creation of `clsLabel` because apparently it couldn't find the symbol anymore when the data type changed, unless I moved it to within the `for` loop.

Comment: Based on a cursory glance, its possible the indexes do not line up, so `i` may cause you to go out of bounds. The function returns an array of results, not a single result stored at the index `i`. You will need to loop through the result set to get what you are expecting. `for(double d : clsLabel) { write(Double.toString(d)) }`

Comment: @HackR (well it truncates your name when using "-"). That may not be all of it, but its a start I believe. If that works I'll reword my comment as an answer.

Comment: @Brendan Update -- yes that totally worked! :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewording my comment.

The result that you get back from `clf.distributionForInstance(newTest.instance(i));` is itself a `double[]`. What this means is not that you get one value back from the distribution function, but the whole distribution as an array of values.

To properly display the overall distribution, you need to loop over the result set individually and print the values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < labeled.size(); i++) {
     double[] clsLabel = clf.distributionForInstance(newTest.instance(i));
     for(double d : clsLabel) {
         outFile.write(Double.toString(d));
     }
     outFile.write("\n");
}
```

Assuming there are 2 classes (2 categories being predicted, like "spam" and "not spam") the following works:

```
BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("silverbullet_rro_output.csv"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < labeled.size(); i++)      
{
    double[] clsLabel = clf.distributionForInstance(newTest.instance(i));
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
       builder.append(clsLabel[j]+""); 
       if(j < clsLabel.length - 1)
           builder.append(",");
    }
    builder.append("\n");
}
outFile.write(builder.toString());//save the string representation
System.out.println("Output file written.");
System.out.println("Completed successfully!");
outFile.close();
```

Comment: Thanks much. The only thing I am doing differently right now is that I put the new line part within the loop. Since there are 2 classes per row this gives me 2x as many rows as I need, but I can fix that bit pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your output will be something like a pivot table, with the class labels as columns and a score for every class returned from your classfier I presume, you'll need to loop over the array and make either a field for each value, or just list the values. I don't know how the values in the double[] array correlate to the class labels, but somehow you'll have to make that association.
Perhaps if the classifier cannot classify, it returns an empty array, which is why you're getting the IOOB exception.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like you and Brendon are describing the same thing. I am giving it a try now. **Update**: This is correct. The code in Brendon's answer made it easier to test so I will mark his as the answer but I will upvote yours too. Thanks again.